# SQL WHERE IN with Left Join is not returning all rows I expect

Tags: mysql, sql, where-in, correspondence

I'm building a little conjugation/radicalization app, and I have stumbled upon a problem. I have this SQL request:

```
SELECT    DISTINCT RA.* 
FROM      radical RA 
left join conjugated CO 
on        CO.word_id = RA.id 
where     CO.conjugation IN ('I', 'am', 'a', 'cat')
```

That returns:

```
| id | radical |
| 13 |  to be  |
```

However, I would like to get a result of the type:

```
| id   | radical | word |
| null |  null   |  I   |
|  13  | to be   | am   |
| null |  null   |  a   |
| null |  null   | cat  |
```

Does anyone know how?

Comment: Please post your sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seemingly you are using a `Left` Join, when you actually need a `Right` join (since it appears you want all rows of the right table matching the predicate to be returned)

So either switch the join:

```
SELECT    DISTINCT RA.*, co.`conjugated` as word
FROM      radical RA 
right join conjugated CO 
on        CO.word_id = RA.id 
where     CO.conjugation IN ('I', 'am', 'a', 'cat');
```

Or switch the order of the tables in the FROM:

```
SELECT    DISTINCT RA.*, co.`conjugated` as word
FROM      conjugated CO 
left join radical RA 
on        CO.word_id = RA.id 
where     CO.conjugation IN ('I', 'am', 'a', 'cat');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a `left join`, but to start with all the words you want to keep:

```
select w.word, ra.* 
from (select 'I' as word union all
      select 'am' union all select 'a' union all select 'cat'
     ) w left join
     conjugated co
     on co.conjugation = w.word left join
     radical ra
     on ra.id = co.word_id;
```

If these values are in `conjugation`, you can simply do:

```
select c.onjugation, ra.* 
from conjugated co left join
     radical ra
     on ra.id = co.word_id
where c.conjugation in ('I', 'am', 'a', 'cat') ;
```

That is, `conjugation` should be first, because you want to keep all matching rows in that table.